# How to share HTML content in UIActivityController?

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have tried this sample code:

```
let websiteURL = "https://www.w3schools.com"
        let htmlText = "<html><a href=\(websiteURL)>" +
        "<img border="+"0"+" src= \(websiteURL)" + " width=100" + " height=100>"
        + "</a></html>"

testOBJ = NSArray(objects: SHARING_TEXT,htmlText)

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: testOBJ as! [AnyObject], applicationActivities: nil)
presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It doesn't work it is displaying text as it is on facebook

[image: click here to see result on facebook]

Comment: use below code - to convert html text into Attributed String


let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!,
                                              options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                                              documentAttributes: nil)

Comment: Not working...! :(